# Configure IIS Express 8 to enable CORS

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, cross-domain, cors, iis-express

I'm writing WCF services that will be used by clients out in the wild so they need to handle cross-origin requests. I have a problem with enabling my development server to accept such requests. Here is the scenario:

- I'm running the WCF project in an instance of Visual Studio 2012, using IIS Express 8 as the server on a specific port.
- I'm running the client project in another instance of Visual Studio 2012, also using IIS Express 8 as the server. This project uses AJAX to consume services in the other project.

When I run the client project in IE there is no problem because IE does not send the preflight OPTIONS request. When I run it in Chrome however the preflight OPTIONS request returns a 405 Method Not Allowed and Chrome gives up on the service. Previous versions of Chrome would just ignore the error and continue with the actual POST request (or Get, whatever...) but later versions appear to be pickier.

I've also run into this with a deployed WCF project and solved it by moving the OPTIONSVerbHandler to the top of the Handler Mappings list in IIS.

I should point out that I'm using the most generous web.config settings I can think of to try to allow CORS. For instance I have this in the WCF project's configuration:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
    <add name="X-Powered-By" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Regardless, any client cross-origin requests to the WCF project running from code fail with the 405 error.

Any help setting up either the WCF project itself or IIS Express 8 to enable CORS?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using WCF services for REST? You might actually want to remove the `OptionsVerbHandler` and handle that yourself. Alternatively...you might want to expose `JSONP`. I recommend that you use `ASP.Net Web-API`.

Comment: After years, it is now possible to use CORS module on IIS Express https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-install-microsoft-cors-module-for-iis-express-7ac24e4c3bc4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the configuration needed to enable WCF to accept CORS preflight messages has nothing to do with the IIS server; rather the WCF project itself needs to be configured to handle the HTTP request with OPTIONS verb.

Long story short: doing this is REALLY HARD. WCF is a jack of all trades when it comes to endpoints so setting it up to do something very specific with one (HTTP) is not advisable, although it can be done. The real solution is to use Web API, which is a master of HTTP and can be set up to do CORS very simply.

Comment: Sometimes the key to finding an answer is to limit the scope of viable answers. This helped. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

You can enable cors for wcf, and it could be quite simple, once you know how.

Elaborating from DavidG response on the more general question ["cors on IIS"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16229340/1178314), response which is really near of what is required for a basic solution:

- First, configure the `OPTIONSVerbHandler` to execute before .Net handlers.

  1. In IIS console, select "Handler Mappings". (Do this either on server level or site level. On site level it will redefine all the handlers for your site and ignore any change done on server level after that. And of course on server level, this could break other sites if they need their own handling of options verb.)
  2. In Action pane, select "View ordered list...". Seek `OPTIONSVerbHandler`, and move it up (lots of clicks...).

  You can also do this in web.config by redefining all handlers under `<system.webServer><handlers>`. (`<clear>` then `<add ...>` them back, this is what does the IIS console for you. By the way, there is no need to ask for "read" permission on this handler.)
- Second, configure custom http headers for your cors needs, such as:

  ```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  ```

  This example set them for all responses to all requests on the site/app/directory in which is the web.config. If you want to restrict them to some url, put that in a `<location>` tag.
  You can also add those custom headers in IIS console.

This is a basic solution since it will send CORS headers even on request which does not require it, maybe opening your application to unexpected usages. But with WCF, it looks like being the simplest one.

With MVC or webapi, we could instead handle `OPTIONS` verb and cors headers by code (either "manually" or with built-in support available in latest version of webapi).

Comment: I am having same problem, I followed the steps above. But it did not yield the desired result. The headers requested and the headers allowed in the response match word to word but it still fails. Please help

Comment: @SivaSenthil, if moreover the response status to the OPTIONS request is 200 in your case, it is probably no more an IIS/WCF trouble.

Comment: @Fredric, unfortunately the OPTIONS request fails with 400 - Bad request status.

Comment: @SivaSenthil, then it looks like the OPTIONSVerbHandler does not execute before .Net handlers. If you have set its execution order on server level, check that it is not undone on site level.

Answer (score 3):

- as a value is only valid for Access-Control-Allow-Origin. For the others you need to be explicit. For example:

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE

or alternatively:

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, DELETE

because the spec says GET and POST are implied.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly though, changing the web.config entry to this:
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="OPTIONS, POST" />
has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to mention, that as of this writing, I don't believe that web browsers support the * wildcard value for `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` or `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` even though it's in the spec.

Spec:

https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2

See Compatibility Notes (easier reading):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

In lieu of the above, better solutions, this means that you have to *explicitly* provide each and every header or method you want to allow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is really hard as `djo.dadof2` says.  One of the answers above talks about using the IIS console, but the question is about IIS Express.  To be fair it talks about moving the `OPTIONSVerbHandler` higher which may in fact work in IIS Express, but you have to clear all the handlers and add them back, which without a console such as IIS has, is difficult as you don't know which ones to add back.  From this answer, [Call WCF service from JQuery : cross-origin OPTIONS request gives error 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874320/call-wcf-service-from-jquery-cross-origin-options-request-gives-error-400), you can see that all you really need to do is handle the OPTIONS request in Global.asax.cs, `Application_BeginRequest`.  I added

```
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
```

And together with

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="null" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

in the webconfig `system.webServer` section that worked for me.  Note that I used `content-type` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header to match what Firefox was sending, and `null` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as I was opening an html page from the local drive.